# c++11 use condition variable in signal handler

Tags: c++, c++11, signals, posix

Is it safe to use [`std::condition_variable::notify_one`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/notify_one) in signal handler? Example:

```
enum State {
  DoNot,
  Do,
};
State state;
std::mutex mutex;

// worker thread
std::thread th = std::thread([]()
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lc(mutex);
    cv.wait(lc, []() { return state; });
});

//signal handler
void handler(int sig)
{
    if (sig == SOME_SIG)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lc(mutex);
        state = Do;
        cv.notify_one();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A C++14 draft standard [N4296](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) says:

> **[support.runtime]/10** The common subset of the C and C++ languages consists of all declarations, definitions, and expressions
>   that may appear in a well formed C++ program and also in a conforming C program. A POF (“plain old
>   function”) is a function that uses only features from this common subset, and that does not directly or indirectly use any function that is not a POF, except that it may use plain lock-free atomic operations... **The behavior of any
>   function other than a POF used as a signal handler in a C++ program is implementation-defined.**

Emphasis mine.

Comment: C++14 draft standard, [N4296](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf).

Comment: To summarize this rather unhelpful answer, no you cannot use a condition variable because it is not `a feature from the common subset`.