# cv.notify_all() is not returning in the main thread during shutdown

Tags: c++, multithreading, threadpool, mutex

I was implementing the producer consumer problem using a thread pool. I am using a mutex on the job_queue and a conditional variable to check if the queue has data. I am trying to implement a gracefull shutdown so I am using a shutdown_flag which is set by the producer thread. The producer thread on getting a SIGINT sets the shutdown_flag and tries to notify_all but is being blocked at this line and the sleeping consumer threads are also not waking up.
Here is the code:

```
#include "thread_pool.h"

template<typename strct>
Thread_pool<strct>::Thread_pool(){}

template<typename strct>
template<typename func_ptr,typename shut_func_ptr>
void Thread_pool<strct>::spawn(int pool_size,int queue_size,func_ptr func,shut_func_ptr shut_func){
    this->pool_size = pool_size;
    job_queue_size = queue_size;
    mtid = pthread_self();

    for(int i=0;i<pool_size;i++){
        std::thread th(&Thread_pool::thread_handle<func_ptr,shut_func_ptr>,this,(i+1),func,shut_func);
        thread_ids.push_back(th.native_handle());
        pool.push_back(std::move(th));
    }
}

template<typename strct>
void Thread_pool<strct>::add_job(strct struc){
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(job_queue_mutex);
    cv.wait(lck,[this]{return job_queue.size()<job_queue_size;});
    job_queue.push(struc);
    lck.unlock();
    cv.notify_all();
}


template<typename strct>
template<typename func_ptr,typename shut_func_ptr>
void Thread_pool<strct>::thread_handle(int thread_id,func_ptr func,shut_func_ptr shut_func){

    while(1){
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(job_queue_mutex);

    while(job_queue.empty() && !shutdown_flag){
        std::cout<<"in wait"<<std::endl;
        cv.wait(lck);
    }
    if(shutdown_flag){
        lck.unlock();
        shut_func();
        break;
    }

    strct param = job_queue.front();
    job_queue.pop();
    cv.notify_all();
    lck.unlock();
    func(param);
    }
}

template<typename strct>
void Thread_pool<strct>::shut_down(){
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(job_queue_mutex);
    shutdown_flag = 1;
    lck.unlock();
    cv.notify_all();
    std::cout<<"notified all"<<std::endl;

    for(auto &th:pool){
        th.join();
    }
}

//DEMO Code

void f(int a){
    std::cout<<a<<"\n";
}

void shutf(){
    std::cout<<"Bye"<<std::endl;
}

Thread_pool<int> pool;

void main_shut_handler(int arg){
    pool.shut_down();
    exit(1);
}

int main(int argc,char* argv[]){

    struct sigaction sa1 = {0};
    sa1.sa_handler = &main_shut_handler;
    sigaction(SIGINT,&sa1,nullptr);

    pool.spawn(1,5,f,shutf);

    for(int j=0;j<10;j++){
        pool.add_job(j);
    }
    while(1);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Work around, using a global `shutdown_flag` and then changing the signal handler to

```
void main_shut_handler(int arg){
  shutdown_flag = true;
}
```

and

```
while(1);
```

to

```
while (!shutdown_flag);
pool.shut_down();
```

might solve your problem.

At some time in the (near? 2023?) future both C and C++ will be able to use the same atomic types then the `while` can be programmed more energy efficient like

```
shutdown_flag.wait();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do extremely limited things in a signal handler.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/31521467/1774667

You have to do the intersection of C and C++ features *only*.  This will require not using C++ constructs in the signal handler.