# C++14: Usage of condition variable in signal handler if only one signal is handled at any given time (exclusion using atomic bool)

Tags: c++, multithreading, signals

I am aware that by default condition variable usage in a signal handler is not safe ([c++11 use condition variable in signal handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31521182/c11-use-condition-variable-in-signal-handler)). However, as per https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html, it seems to imply that if we ensure that no other signals are getting processed during this time, it maybe okay to do so.

> 2. Block signal delivery in the main program when calling functions that are unsafe or operating on global data that is also accessed by the signal handler.

So, if I use a std::atomic_bool to ensure that only one handling is running at any time, is usage of condition variable safe? Something like in the code below (simplified a lot):

```
std::atomic_bool g_signalBlock; // global 

void handleSignal(int signalNumber, siginfo_t* signalInfo, void* ucontext) {
    if (g_signalBlock.exchange(true)) {
        return; // ignore this signal. another signal being processed.
    } else {
       // process the signal
       if (signalNumber == SIGUSR2) {
         // notify another thread using std::condition_variable
       } else {
         // re-raise non-SIGUSR2 signal (to exit the program) 
         signal(signalNumber, SIG_DFL);
         raise(signal);
       }

       g_signalBlock.store(false);  // now allow other signals
    }
}
```

Use case:

As part of signal handling logic, there are certain operations that are currently async-signal-safe but takes too long (logging to files which is implemented in a async-signal-safe manner). This is acceptable for signals like SIGABRT etc. where the process is going to exit, but the same handler is also used for handling SIGUSR2 signals to log thread traces (automatically triggered under certain conditions). I want to avoid it impacting other threads, thus a need to delegate logging to a background thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not enough to merely ensure that only one signal handler can be running at a time. A signal handler can race against any thread in your program.

So if you have a condition variable `cv`, and you access it from within a signal handler, you must ensure that that signal handler cannot be invoked while any other code that accesses `cv` is running. The only way to do this is to either change the action that will be taken when a signal is received (*e.g.*, ignore the signal or terminate the process) or mask out the signal (*e.g.* using `sigprocmask`) prior to executing the code that accesses `cv`.

You might find this strange. If two threads can concurrently access `cv` then why can't one thread and one signal handler safely concurrently access `cv`? Well, all thread-safe types need to guard against a second thread trying to do something with them while the first thread is in the middle of something. But if a thread is in the middle of doing something with the variable, and then that thread gets interrupted in order to execute the signal handler (which executes on *the very same thread*), which tries to do something with the same variable, the implementation won't necessarily be able to handle that kind of same-thread re-entrancy properly.

Only lock-free atomics can offer the guarantee that a single operation truly is indivisible from the hardware's point of view, and therefore, it is impossible for a thread to get interrupted to run a signal handler while it's in the middle of accessing the variable.

If you were hoping to have the signal handler add something to a queue and then notify the condition variable to let some thread know that the queue is nonempty, unfortunately, the standard just doesn't allow that. The signal handler should communicate with the rest of the program solely using lock-free atomic variables. Since C++20, atomic variables themselves support `wait`, `notify_one` and `notify_all` operations, so you can use those. Prior to C++20, the options aren't that great; you could (1) use platform-specific functionality like futexes, (2) communicate using signal-safe library functions; for example, the signal handler can `write` to a file descriptor and this can wake up another thread that's blocked on a `read`; or (3) have a thread that just spins until the value of an atomic variable changes.

Answer (score 1):

According to cppreference, you can use STL's atomics in a signal handler as long as they are lock-free.

See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/signal

But you cannot use the `std::condition_variable` to notify a thread. It was straight up written to be not safe operation in signal handlers. Besides, applying `notify_one()` without first locking and unlocking its associated mutex is a bad idea.

Instead, you can use simpler waiting schemes: one threads checks every 10ms what's status of the atomic variables that signal handler modifies and performs all necessary updates and notification. These have lag of up to 10ms, but it shouldn't be a big problem.

There's atomic's `notify_one` that is available in C++20. Though not entirely sure if that's safe in signal.

Comment: But the question is about the condition variable.

Comment: @user17732522 I don't see any condition variables in the code... wait he commented it out. I'll fix it.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not async-safe.

```
// notify another thread using std::condition_variable
```

Well, in addition to this particular execution thread, some other execution thread, might also be using this `std::condition_variable`. Surprise!

Your proposed logic is sufficient to guarantee async-safety *in this signal handler*.

But it takes two to tango.

If this condition variable is used only here, and nowhere else, then this would be async-safe. But, of course, this is not the case. It would be pretty pointless to have a condition variable that's only accessed right here. It must be accessed somewhere else, too. Game over.

Let's re-read this part, slowly:

> Block signal delivery [when] operating on global data that
> is also accessed by the signal handler.

Not only this block must be in place in the signal handler itself, but any time any other execution thread even sneezes in the same direction as this condition variable, the signal handler must be blocked from accessing it. That's what this says.

This is telling you: whenever you have something in any execution thread accessing global data, you must block the signal handler from accessing it. Yes, this means the condition variable. Every time you access it from another execution thread, you must block the signal.

The blocking within the signal handler itself is just a special case of the "global data" already being "accessed by the signal handler". It'a already being accessed -- by the first, initial, invocation of the signal handler.